# Adding event listener in alexa ask-sdk

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

I hava basic alexa skill in JAVA (using ask-sdk)
one scenario is that on a specific time i want Alexa to say some notification , like at 2:00(which will be determined by my code) alexa should say something

"its 2.00" you must go for walk ..

But I am not sure what to use for this , I see some Alerts/Proactive events , But not able to find them for JAVA , only see them in nodeJs.

is anything for this situation availabe in java please..

Comment: You don't need a skill for it. You can create a routine that will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

The Proactive Events API is language agnostic, you can make calls to it in your Java code to trigger the notification that you want.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html